# How to plot remote image (from http url)

Tags: matplotlib

This must be easy, but I can't figure how right now without using urllib module and manually fetching remote file

I want to overlay plot with remote image (let's say "http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/_static/logo2.png"), and neither `imshow()` nor `imread()` can load the image.

Any ideas which function will allow loading remote image?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is easy indeed:

```
import urllib2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create a file-like object from the url
f = urllib2.urlopen("http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/_static/logo2.png")

# read the image file in a numpy array
a = plt.imread(f)
plt.imshow(a)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Well I was hoping that MPL can do this w/o urllib, but maybe it can't. I'll wait a bit more and if it's indeed impossible I'll mark you answer

Comment: Looking at the docs I don't think it's possible. And it's only 2 lines extra here, no big deal.

Comment: For python 3, import `urllib` instead of `urllib2` and call `urllib.request.urlopen` instead of `urllib2.urlopen`.

Comment: Also, imread cannot guess the filetype from a stream like this. It defaults to PNG so this works for PNGs only. For non-PNG files, one needs to pass the format parameter to imread (e.g. format='jpg'). This requires additional work to extract the filetype from the url.

Answer (score 19):

This works for me in a notebook with python 3.5:

```
from skimage import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = io.imread(url)
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I got `ValueError: invalid PNG header` for the `urllib2` solution but this worked well for me

Comment: To get skimage, `pip install scikit-image`

Comment: Worked for me! (base:conda)

Comment: this didn't work for me because skimage.io prepends my current working directory to the S3 url

Answer (score 15):

you can do it with this code;

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
a = plt.imread("http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/_static/logo2.png")
plt.imshow(a)
plt.show()
```

Comment: How would you suggest handling 403 errors?

Comment: this doesn't work for S3 urls: `URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: s3>`

Comment: Directly reading images from URLs is deprecated, it is recommended to open the URL for reading and pass the result to Pillow, e.g. with ``np.array(PIL.Image.open(urllib.request.urlopen(url)))``

Answer (score 2):

`pyplot.imread` for URLs is [deprecated](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imread.html)

> Passing a URL is deprecated. Please open the URL for reading and pass
> the result to Pillow, e.g. with
> np.array(PIL.Image.open(urllib.request.urlopen(url))).

Matplotlib suggests using PIL instead. I prefer using [`imageio`](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/v2.9.0/userapi.html#imageio.imread) as sugested by [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html):

> imread is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0. Use
> imageio.imread instead.

`imageio.imread(uri, format=None, **kwargs)`

> Reads an image from the specified file. Returns a numpy array, which
> comes with a dict of meta data at its ‘meta’ attribute.
>
> Note that the image data is returned as-is, and may not always have a
> dtype of uint8 (and thus may differ from what e.g. PIL returns).

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from imageio import imread

url = "http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/_static/logo2.png"
img = imread(url)
plt.imshow(img)
```