# imread not working for online jpg files

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am using the Anaconda distribution of Jupyter, and I'm having trouble using `matplotlib.pylab.imread` reading .jpg files from the internet, even though reading local jpg files works fine. Any way to fix this? I included my code and error log below

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

LIFE = plt.imread("LIFE.jpg", format="jpg") # local file
LIFE = plt.imread("http://2neatmagazines.com/Life-Magazine-Covers/1969/Life-Magazine-1969-08-11.jpg", format="jpg")

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-065a192e7dc8> in <module>()
      3 
      4 LIFE = plt.imread("LIFE.jpg", format="jpg")
----> 5 LIFE = plt.imread("http://2neatmagazines.com/Life-Magazine-Covers/1969/Life-Magazine-1969-08-11.jpg", format="jpg")

C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in imread(*args, **kwargs)
   2295 @docstring.copy_dedent(_imread)
   2296 def imread(*args, **kwargs):
-> 2297     return _imread(*args, **kwargs)
   2298 
   2299 

C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in imread(fname, format)
   1304 
   1305     if ext not in handlers:
-> 1306         im = pilread(fname)
   1307         if im is None:
   1308             raise ValueError('Only know how to handle extensions: %s; '

C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in pilread(fname)
   1282         except ImportError:
   1283             return None
-> 1284         image = Image.open(fname)
   1285         return pil_to_array(image)
   1286 

C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2278             filename = str(fp.resolve())
   2279     if filename:
-> 2280         fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
   2281 
   2282     try:

IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'http://2neatmagazines.com/Life-Magazine-Covers/1969/Life-Magazine-1969-08-11.jpg'
```

Note: I have tried `matplotlib.image.imread` and `scipy.misc.imread`, both fail with the same error

**SOLUTION:**

I was directed to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116050/how-to-plot-remote-image-from-http-url) to a similar question, which solved my issue. Note that for JPG files, you have to add the `format` argument, like

```
a = plt.imread(f, format="jpg")
```

Comment: From the [fine documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/image_api.html#matplotlib.image.imread) `matplotlib can only read PNGs natively, but if PIL is installed, it will use it to load the image and return an array (if possible) which can be used with imshow(). Note, URL strings may not be compatible with PIL. Check the PIL documentation for more information.`

Comment: @DeepSpace that did fix my problem, thanks for the link. I somehow must have missed that while searching for this problem