# Display TIFF Image On Juypyter Notebook using Python Without Saving / Downloading

Tags: python, matplotlib, httprequest, jupyter-notebook, tiff

I am working with web services using requests to get an image based on parameters passed. The first response I get is a XML schema with file reference URL.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Coverages schemaLocation="http://localhost/server/schemas/wcs/1.1.1/wcsCoverages.xsd">
<Coverage>
    <Title>Filename</Title>
    <Abstract/>
    <Identifier>Filename</Identifier>
    <Reference href="http://localhost/server/temp/filename.tif"/>
</Coverage>
</Coverages>
```

Next using `xml.etree.ElementTree` I extracted the URL. Next what I need is to dsiplay that tiff image (or any other image) on the Jupyter Notebook without **downloading** (as one image can be more than 50 or 100 MB sometimes)

Currently I am downloading and plotting the file after reading and converting file data into array ( as pyplot plot image array/matrix ).

```
import requests as req # request wcs urls
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET # used for xml parsing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # display image
import gdal

# Download the File to local directory using Chunks 
    chunk_size=1024
    local_filename = url.split('/')[-1] # Filename from url
    r = req.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size): 
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)

    # Read File Raster Data as Array using Gdal
    gtif = gdal.Open(local_filename)
    georaster = gtif.ReadAsArray()

    # Plot image using matplotlib
    plt.imshow(georaster)
    plt.title(local_filename)
    plt.show()
```

So is there any way to convert the raw response from requests API for file directly into image array (in chunks or whole) and display it on notebook (without downloading and taking space on local directory)

The raw response from get request for tiff file is below

```
resp2 = req.get('tiffFielurl')
rawdata = resp2.content
rawdata[0:10]

Output: b'MM\x00*\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x10'
```

I tried searching for this question but not found any good answer on it so if there is any related question or duplicate provide me the link.

Comment: You can display a remote image using Matplotlib as outlined in this similar StackOverflow question: [How to plot remote image (from http url)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116050/how-to-plot-remote-image-from-http-url).

Comment: @Brian Seems like the solution mentioned on link you have given is working with "PNG" files only, I tried requesting TIFF file and get following error. 

" **ValueError: invalid PNG header** "

Comment: Actually, after trying a number of different methods, I'm not able to find anything that plays well with tiff files from a url (at least in my hands). You might try using io.BytesIO or np.fromstring or np.frombuffer. I will not be able to help you further without knowing more about your image data (expected data type and size) and having access to an example I can reproduce. Good luck and let me know if you find anything that does work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try plotting tiff images using [ipyplot](https://github.com/karolzak/ipyplot) package

```py
import ipyplot

ipyplot.plot_images(
    ['https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/file_example_TIFF_1MB.tiff',
    'https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/file_example_TIFF_1MB.tiff',
    'https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/file_example_TIFF_1MB.tiff'],
    img_width=250)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After doing so much research and trying different solutions it seems to me the only way to do the above procedure i.e displaying Tiff file for now is **downloading and reading the data using gdal and converting into array and display using matplotlib** .

As the solution mentioned in following link is only accepting "PNG" files.

[How to plot remote image (from http url)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116050/how-to-plot-remote-image-from-http-url)

whcih comes to conclusion we need PIL library that I also tried and fails.

```
from PIL import Image
resp2 = req.get('tiffFielurl')
resp2.raw.decode_content = True
im = Image.open(resp2.raw)
im
```

Gives Output:

```
<PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile image mode=I;16BS size=4800x4800 at 0x11CB7C50>
```

and converting the PIL object to numpy array or even getting data or pixels from PIL object gives error of unrecognized mode error.

```
im.getdata()
im.getpixels((0,0))
numpy.array(im)
```

All gives same error

```
    257         if not self.im or\
    258            self.im.mode != self.mode or self.im.size != self.size:
--> 259             self.im = Image.core.new(self.mode, self.size)
    260         # create palette (optional)
    261         if self.mode == "P":

ValueError: unrecognized mode
```

It comes out that PIL even don't support 16bit Signed integer pixel that is defined in Tiff object of PIL above.

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes